# Autodesk Forge Model Derivative API: TranslationWorker-InternalFailure

Tags: autodesk-model-derivative

I am attempting to translate an .rvt file to svf using the following call using the model derivative forge api. I am uploading a single rvt file and the file is not corrupt

```
POST /modelderivative/v2/designdata/job HTTP/1.1
Host: developer.api.autodesk.com
Authorization: Bearer 
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
x-ads-force: true
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: a05c2308-6b4f-7a3f-57b0-2916f25d0157

{
    "input": {
        "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Zm9yZ2V0ZXN0c3AvV0lMRC5ydnQ=",
        "compressedUrn": true,
        "rootFilename": "WILD.rvt"
    },
    "output": {
        "destination": {
            "region": "us"
        },
        "formats": [
        {
            "type": "svf", 
            "views": ["2d"]
        }]
    }
}
```

Here is the response I get. Not sure what is wrong. Please help

```
{
    "type": "manifest",
    "hasThumbnail": "false",
    "status": "failed",
    "progress": "complete",
    "region": "US",
    "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Zm9yZ2V0ZXN0c3AvV0lMRC5ydnQ",
    "version": "1.0",
    "derivatives": [
        {
            "name": "LMV Bubble",
            "hasThumbnail": "false",
            "status": "failed",
            "progress": "complete",
            "messages": [
                {
                    "type": "error",
                    "message": "Tr worker fail to download.",
                    "code": "TranslationWorker-InternalFailure"
                }
            ],
            "outputType": "svf"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you translating a RVT and not an archive (ZIP) so remove the `"compressedUrn": true, "rootFilename": "WILD.rvt"` (which is for archives and their root files) bit from your job request payload:

```
{
    "input": {
        "urn": "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6Zm9yZ2V0ZXN0c3AvV0lMRC5ydnQ="
    },
    "output": {
        "destination": {
            "region": "us"
        },
        "formats": [
        {
            "type": "svf", 
            "views": ["2d"]
        }]
    }
}
```